# Using TDS project items in FakeDb.Serialization

Tags: tds, unit-testing, fakedb

I have a test project for a module where I'd like to use `FakeDb`. Because I have a `TDS` project where store items for `master` database, I'd like to use them for tests with `FakeDb.Serialization`.

When I set the relative path to folder in test project to my TDS project, and I run the tests `FakeDb.Serialization` is complaining that it can't find the items. It's looking in my user's directory, not the solution directory.

Any ideas how to handle that? Or maybe there is another approach to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

My problem was actually due to ReSharper Unit Test for NUnit runner. It was running tests from temporary location, not from the project output directory.

Fix was to tell NUnit runner to set Environment.CurrentDirectory to Test assembly's folder:
[image]